# $.Deferred not deferring

Tags: jquery, asynchronous

When I step through mys code in the debugger I can see var answer giving me what I expect but when the function finishes it shows as undefined. Can someone please even point me in the right direction? I've read the docs and can't see where I'm going wrong. Code is as follows:

```
function hasTimeAccountData(aktivEmployee) {
        this.aktivEmployee = aktivEmployee;
        var deferred = new $.Deferred();
        callService("GetEmployee",
            { employeeNo: aktivEmployee.id},
            function (result) {
                var answer = result.HasTimeAccountData;
                deferred.resolve(answer);
            });
        return deferred.promise();
    }

function callService(functionName, data, onSuccess, onTimeout) {
    var timeout;
    if (onTimeout) timeout = setTimeout(onTimeout, 10000);
    var server = lStorage.getServerUrl();
    if (!server) server = getDefaultAddress();
    var url = server + functionName;
    $.ajax({
        dataType: "jsonp",
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: function (data) {
            clearTimeout(timeout);
            if (onSuccess) onSuccess(data);
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: What exactly is undefined???

Comment: @A.Wolff - when I call (hasTimeAccountData(employee)===false) the debugger shows the function as undefined, even though i see it being called and stepped through in the debugger, it even gives var answer a value and then washes it all away...

Comment: @rory Its hard to tell from your question, but I think the trouble you're having is that it *is* deferring - thats what deferred's and promises do (defer async events), but what it isn't doing is "awaiting".  So it won't wait for the response and then return that,  promises aren't designed to do that if that is what you're expecting.  Check out my answer for a bit more on promises.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think its important to remember that `hasTimeAccountData` is returning a promise, so it cannot be immediately evaluated with the expectation that it will return the successful result of that promise.  So the code you included in your comment `(hasTimeAccountData(employee)===false)` won't work.

You need to use the methods of the promise object and introduce callbacks that will respond to the different outcomes of that promise.  ie.

```
hasTimeAccountData(employee)
        .then(showEmployeeData, showErrorMessage);
```

[Here is a detailed test case fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/99eTc/) that I've put together to show one way that you can respond to the different outcomes of the promise.  I've expanded `hasTimeAccountData` to also invoke promise rejections when things go wrong...

```
function hasTimeAccountData(aktivEmployee) {
    var deferred = new $.Deferred();    

    this.aktivEmployee = aktivEmployee;

    callService(
        "GetEmployee", 
        { employeeNo: aktivEmployee.id },
        function success(result) {
            if (result.hasOwnProperty("HasTimeAccountData")) {
                deferred.resolve(result.HasTimeAccountData);
            }
            else {
                deferred.reject("no time account data field in return data!");
            }
        },
        function timeout() {
            deferred.reject("timeout occurred");
        }
    );

    return deferred.promise();
}
```

I mocked out the `callService` method to illustrate the point.

I hope this helps, if not check out the [jQuery docs on this](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.promise/), they're really good.

Comment: Wow, talking about above and beyond! Thank you so much Stephen!